# Reference for partial Hadamard matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

**Definition.** An $m\times n$ matrix is said to be a partial Hadamard matrix (let's say PHM) if its entries are chosen from $\lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace$ such that the dot product of each pair of row vectors is $0$.

**Details.** This of course relates to the famous Hadamard conjecture which looks at $m=n$, but I am interested in the weaker $m<n$ case. Specifically, I am wondering about how many distinct $m\times n$ PHM exist given some, say $2$, of the row vectors, up to row permutation - as well as their construction.

**Questions.** What are some good resources on results known about PHM? Are there iconic papers in the field?

Comment: I imagine doing a web search on "partial Hadamard" will go far towards answering your question.  Further checking resources such as the handbook of combinatorial designs should provide decent references.

Comment: I searched before posting and Google yielded little outside sources making superficial observations. I'll check out that handbook, thanks.

Comment: Did your web search turn up this paper? http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s12095-010-0033-z  I'm not sure it addresses exactly what you're looking for, but it's certainly not superficial.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the key results on partial Hadamard matrices are due to De Launey, going back to his 2000 paper *On the asymptotic existence of partial complex Hadamard matrices and related combinatorial objects.* [Discrete Applied Mathematics 102, 37–45, (2000)]. You can find references in one of his most recent papers, [A Fourier-analytic Approach to Counting Partial Hadamard Matrices](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1003.4003) (which is the one mentioned by Mark Meckes). A slightly more recent reference is [Searching for partial Hadamard matrices](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1201.4021).

Answer (score 2):

One great paper that I recently became aware of on this topic is 
``[Integral Rational Completions of Combinatorial Matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(78)90019-5)" by Eric Verheiden
in the Journal of Combinatorial Theory Series A (1978).
This paper studies extendebility of partial Hadamard matrices to Hadamard matrices.
In particular, it is proven that any partial $n-r \times n$ Hadamard matrix can be extended to an $n \times n$ Hadamard matrix if $r \leq 7$.

It is not possible to improve this result as there are many examples of 
$n-8 \times n$ partial Hadamard matrices that cannot be extended to a Hadamard matrix, see ``[A counter example to Beder's conjectures about Hadamard matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jspi.2009.02.003)" in Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference (2009) by Bulutoglu and Kaziska.

Answer (score 0):

Another paper on this topic is:
Goldberger, A., Strassler, Y., A practical algorithm for completing half-Hadamard matrices using LLL, Journal of Algebraic Combinatorics, Volume 55, pages 217–244, (2022).