# Almost Hadamard matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

As well-known, a Hadamard matrix is a square matrix with all coefficients $\pm 1$
and pairwise orthogonal rows or columns. Such matrices exist conjecturally 
in every dimension divisible by $4$. Call a matrix with an odd number $n$ of columns an "almost Hadamard matrix" if all its coefficients are $\pm 1$ and if all scalar products between distinct rows are $\pm 1$. We want to maximize the
number of rows in almost Hadamard matrices: If $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ this is easy:
erase the last column of a Hadamard matrix of size $n+1$ (provided such a matrix exists). This yields a matrix with $n+1$ rows which is best possible. If $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ the number of rows cannot exceed $n$ (argument: up to replacing rows by their opposites, we can suppose that all rows have an even 
number of coefficients $-1$. All scalar products between rows are now 
equivalent to $n$ modulo $4$ and a rank computation of the corresponding Gram matrix gives the result).

A solution with $n-1$ rows in the case $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$
is obtained by adding an arbitrary last column 
(with coefficients $\pm 1$) to a Hadamard matrix of size $n-1$.

For $n=5$ (and of course for $n=1$) there is a solution with $n$ rows but I am
unaware of the existence of solutions with $n$ rows for any $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$
greater than $5$. Are there any?

Is there any literature on such almost Hadamard matrices (perhaps under a different terminology, they are for example related to systems of equiangular lines)?

Comment: According to the computer there are no solutions for n=9 and n=13. It found solution for n=5. Might be wrong.

Comment: Indeed, a solution for $n=5$ is given by considering a symmetric square matrix of size $5$ with $1$ on the diagonal and $-1$ everywhere else.

Comment: Ehlich,  Barba, and Wojtas did the work on matrix determinants for (some permutation of) orders 1,2, and 3 mod 4. Some recent accounts (e.g. Osborn or Orrick) of the Hadamard problem may talk enough about Gram matrices to say why you can't do optimal for 1 mod 4.

Comment: @joro - just found a solution for n=13 (using random rotation-matrices as basis and then using that "varimin"-rotation discussed elsewhere).

Comment: The matrix, in compact form, is `0222000020220022020222202022220220020202000000022000202000220020022002220202200202202002200220200222000222202000000022222220222200220000020222220222020222220220022022202`
where you extract the digits rowwise into a $13\times13$-matrix and subtract $1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find most useful information on [this](http://www.indiana.edu/~maxdet/) page, which however has not been updated since 2012. The initial question is different, but the partial solution they have found is relevant here.

Quote:
**The *Hadamard maximal determinant problem* asks when a matrix of a given order with entries -1 and +1 has the largest possible determinant.**

If the determinant of such an extremal matrix $M=M_n$ for $n\equiv1\pmod4$ attains [Barba's bound](http://www.indiana.edu/~maxdet/bounds.html) $$\sqrt{ (2n-1)  (n-1)^{n-1}},$$ which obviously needs $(2n-1)$ to be a perfect square, then $$M^TM=MM^T=J_n+(n-1)I_n$$ where $J_n$ is the all-$1$-matrix. So this matrix is an "almost Hadamard" (a.H.) matrix. (Moreover, all scalar products are $+1$.)
Examples are given for $n=5,13,25,41,61,113$.
If $2n-1=(2q+1)^2$ and $q$ is a prime power (note that the examples correspond to $q=1,2,3,4,5,7$), there is an explicit construction according to the paper
 *A. E. Brouwer, An infinite series of symmetric designs, Math. Centrum
   Amsterdam Report ZW 202/83 (1983)*.

If $(2n-1)$ is *not* a perfect square at all, we cannot conclude inversely that no square a.H. matrix exists, though I have a (kind of) heuristic argument against its existence:
What we can conclude is that $M^TM$ must have a determinant smaller than Barba's bound because it must be a square. This means that the set of column vectors cannot be split in two sets $V$ and $W$ such that $v^T_iv_j=w_i^Tw_j=+1$ and $v^T_iw_j=-1$. (Nor, similarly, for the rows.)
Before explaining why, here is an illustration of what I mean with those two sets. Take for instance the matrix $M$ given for $n=13$ in [Gottfried Helms' comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156735/almost-hadamard-matrices/314923#comment784094_156735). After some row and column permutations we have 
 $$MM^T=-J_{13}+2J_5\oplus J_8+12I_{13}$$ and $$M^TM=-J_{13}+2J_3\oplus J_{10}+12I_{13},$$ written in compact form: $MM^T=$

```
n 1 1 1 1 - - - - - - - -
1 n 1 1 1 - - - - - - - -
1 1 n 1 1 - - - - - - - -
1 1 1 n 1 - - - - - - - -
1 1 1 1 n - - - - - - - -
- - - - - n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
- - - - - 1 n 1 1 1 1 1 1
- - - - - 1 1 n 1 1 1 1 1
- - - - - 1 1 1 n 1 1 1 1
- - - - - 1 1 1 1 n 1 1 1
- - - - - 1 1 1 1 1 n 1 1
- - - - - 1 1 1 1 1 1 n 1
- - - - - 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 n
```

and similarly for $M^TM$. That is, the rows of $M$ come in two sets of sizes $5$ and $8$, while the columns of $M$ form two sets of sizes $3$ and $10$.
Now *the determinant of such a block matrix is always $(2n-1)  (n-1)^{n-1}$, independently of the block sizes.* So if $(2n-1)$ is not a square, the rows and columns cannot be partitioned in such a way, which means that an $n\times n$ a.H. matrix cannot have this kind of "symmetries". And heuristically, the existence of such a matrix seems to me about as improbable as the existence of a projective plane of non prime-power order...

BUT based on the data of the above site, e.g. [the $n=93$ example](http://www.indiana.edu/~maxdet/d93.html), I would conjecture that $n-1$ almost orthogonal vectors always exist.

Answer (score 6):

If you regard each row of your desired matrix as a sequence of bipolar signals and each column as a time frame, then, with one additional condition that the matrix is circulant, what you're asking becomes a set of bipolar binary sequences whose periodic out-of-phase autocorrelations are either $+1$ or $-1$. Because such sequences are close to optimal for various purposes, most likely there are a bunch of known results in the intersection of information theory, signal processing, and design theory. (The caveat is that when $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, you might be able to have one more row.)

For instance, if you take the [binary $m$-sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence) of period $2^m-1$, its out-of-phase atuocorrelations are always $-1$. Hence, by stacking all the $2^m-1$ cyclic shifts of the sequence, you have a desired square matrix, where the inner product between a pair of rows is always $-1$.

You can exploit this idea with other well-known sequences. For example, the Legendre sequence of period $n$ has optimal autocorrelations if and only if $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, i.e., if $n$ is of the form $4k-1$, its out-of-phase autocorrelations are $-1$ just like $m$-sequences. Hence, all Lengendre sequences of period $n = 4k-1$ can be turned into square matrices with the desired property.

You can use design theory with this sequence approach as well. Take a cyclic difference set $D$ of order $n$, block size $k$, and index $\lambda$. Construct the $n$-dimensional vector $\boldsymbol{a} = (a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})$, where $a_i = -1$ if $i \in D$ and $a_i = 1$ otherwise. Then, it is straightforward to check that the inner product between $\boldsymbol{a}$ and any of its cyclic shift is exactly $n-4(k-\lambda)$ (except when you take the product of exactly the same vectors). Hence, by taking cyclic difference sets satisfying $n-4(k-\lambda) = -1$ or $1$ such as the cyclic $(19,10,5)$ difference set $D = \{0,1,4,5,6,7,9,11,16,17\}$, you obtain a desired square matrix by stacking the cyclic shifts of the corresponding vector.

A good reference book for such sequences that is mathematician-friendly is *Sequence Design for Communications Applications* by P. Fan and M Darnell.

The second edition of *Handbook of Combinatorial Designs* edited by C. J. Colbourn and J. H. Dinitz has a section for "Sequence Correlation" within Chapter "Hadamard Matrices and Related Designs."

I'm not sure if you can construct an $n \times n$ or $(n+1)\times n$ almost Hadamard matrix this way when there is no known Hadamard matrix of size $n$ if you stick with sequences whose out-of-phase autocorrelations are always $-1$. But if you allow them to be either $1$ or $-1$, maybe you can for many values of $n$.

Also, this is somewhat trivial, but your method of adding/deleting columns works for *partial Hadamard matrices*. Fortunately, Seraj made a reference request on partial Hadamard matrix and got a nice answer by Carlo Beenakker here:

[Reference for partial Hadamard matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137698/reference-for-partial-hadamard-matrices)

This should give not necessarily circulant examples with many rows.

I know this "answer" doesn't give a satisfactory answer to your question. But searching the literature (and the internet) with some of the keywords in this post may be a good starting point.